# Cursor not aligning with the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typed.js

I have written a html file and for animations of type writer like thing, I have used typed.js.

The code is as follows

```js
var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
            stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
            smartBackspace:true,
            typeSpeed:100,
            backSpeed:80,
            startDelay:20,
            backDelay:20,
            loop:true,
            showCursor: true,
            cursorChar: '|',
            autoInsertCss: true
        });
```

```css
.center {
    position: relative ;
    top:  50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    /* color: #ffffff; */
  }
  
  .typed-cursor {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 48px;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: blink .7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.6/typed.js"></script>
<div id="typed-strings">
                <p>Myself Big Bounty</p>
                <p>I'm a coder</p>
                <p>I'm ML enthusiast</p>
 </div>
 <span id="typed" class="center"></span>
```

Why is the cursor separating itself from the text? And How should I align the cursor along with the text?

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping the "typed" span in a "centered" div. Like this:

```js
var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
            stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
            smartBackspace:true,
            typeSpeed:100,
            backSpeed:80,
            startDelay:20,
            backDelay:20,
            loop:true,
            showCursor: true,
            cursorChar: '|',
            autoInsertCss: true
        });
```

```css
.center {
    position: relative ;
    top:  50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    /* color: #ffffff; */
  }
  
  .typed-cursor {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 48px;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: blink .7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.6/typed.js"></script>
<div id="typed-strings">
                <p>Myself Big Bounty</p>
                <p>I'm a coder</p>
                <p>I'm ML enthusiast</p>
 </div>
 <div class="center">
    <span id="typed"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: without removing `left: 50%` the text won't center dear

Comment: the OP doesn't say anything about centering, it's just a matter of cursor alignment

Comment: I didn't notice that, my fault sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap the `span` with `div` holding `.center` class also you don't have to put `top` and `left` **which they are causing the issue** replace them with `text-align: center`

```
.center {
    position: relative ;
    text-align: center;
    /* Remove top and left */
    /*top:  50%;*/
    /*left: 50%;*/
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    /* color: #ffffff; */
  }
```

```js
var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
            stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
            smartBackspace:true,
            typeSpeed:100,
            backSpeed:80,
            startDelay:20,
            backDelay:20,
            loop:true,
            showCursor: true,
            cursorChar: '|',
            autoInsertCss: true
        });
```

```css
.center {
    position: relative ;
    text-align: center;
    /*top:  50%;*/
    /*left: 50%;*/
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    /* color: #ffffff; */
  }
  
  .typed-cursor {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 48px;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: blink .7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.6/typed.js"></script>
<div id="typed-strings">
    <p>Myself Big Bounty</p>
    <p>I'm a coder</p>
    <p>I'm ML enthusiast</p>
</div>
<div class="center">
    <span id="typed"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your use of text-align made the div move upwards. Actually I'm making this appear on a background div. So, top and left are required

Comment: this make sense now, because you didn't mention that in your question